# List of definitions

Tags: tables, tabularx

I have a plain-text document that I would convert to LaTeX. The document is not a typical *text* document but a list of definitions including some short prefaces and optionally *"post-faces"*.

Example (Plain text):

```
===============================================================================
3.2.5                          SOME TITLE 1
===============================================================================

                            (Some sub title 1)

   This is an  introduction and a short  text describing the list that follows.
It has some words other words and more words that together is sentences. It has
some words other  words and more words  that together is sentences. It has some 
words other words and more words that together is sentences.  Finally it contin-
ues on and on for a bit. Then after a while it ends.

op3r   Indicates that the operand has three regular indicators defining the dest-
       ination for the long run in the alternate universe.

dym    Follows that the dinner was late.

flux, k3, k4, yz, az
       Property of the beholder is foreseen by the old definition referred by a
       longer run for the start point logged by the initiator.

   Some text after the list that few read but all should. It is the key to solve 
many a question related to the way of deciphering  the meaning of the quirks and
shortcomings.

===============================================================================
3.2.6                          SOME TITLE 2
===============================================================================

                            (Some sub title 2)

   Another introduction and list of definitions.
```

---

Each list of definitions spans about 1 - 4 pages.

As a compromise keywords does not have to be on same line as explanation (where they fit), as with e.g. *op3r* in the rather silly example above. This is done in the plain-text document to make it more compact.

My question is what would be the best way to organize this in a LaTeX document. Is there some package for this kind of definition lists? It is also quite possible I'm going to extend it to include *general text* chapters in the future.

I have played around with using tables, but not sure if the would be the best way. Typically something like *(Edited with more complete example for future readers.)*:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{parskip}
\setlength{\parindent}{20pt}
\begin{document}

%==============================================================================
\section{SOME TITLE 1}
%==============================================================================

\begin{center}
\emph{(Some subtitle 1)}
\end{center}

This is an  introduction and a short  text describing the list that follows.
It has some words other words and more words that together is sentences. It has
some words other  words and more words  that together is sentences. It has some 
words other words and more words that together is sentences.  Finally it contin-
ues on and on for a bit. Then after a while it ends.

\begin{tabularx}{1\textwidth}{ l X }
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{op3r}  \\
    & Indicates that the operand has three regular indicators defining the
destination for the long run in the alternate universe. \\
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{dym}  \\
    & Follows that the dinner was late. \\
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{flux, k3, k4, yz, az} \\
    & Property of the beholder is foreseen by the old definition referred 
by a longer run for the start point logged by the initiator.
\end{tabularx}

Some text after the list that few read but all should. It is the key to solve 
many a question related to the way of deciphering  the meaning of the quirks and
shortcomings.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Tables would not be the easiest way to go here, since they would be very long. While some allow breaking across page boundaries (like [`longtable`](http://ctan.org/pkg/longtable)), it may be more feasible to use lists, since the breaking can occur mid-paragraph (not sure how long your paragraph text would be).

[`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) provides a `style=nextline` option to its description lists that "inserts a line break" for overly long description labels:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}% http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem
\begin{document}

This is an  introduction and a short  text describing the list that follows.
It has some words other words and more words that together is sentences. It has
some words other  words and more words  that together is sentences. It has some 
words other words and more words that together is sentences.  Finally it contin-
ues on and on for a bit. Then after a while it ends.

\begin{description}[font=\sffamily\bfseries, leftmargin=1cm, style=nextline]
  \item[op3r]
    Indicates that the operand has three regular indicators defining the dest-
    ination for the long run in the alternate universe.
  \item[dym]
    Follows that the dinner was late.
  \item[flux, k3, k4, yz, az]
    Property of the beholder is foreseen by the old definition referred by a
    longer run for the start point logged by the initiator.
\end{description}

Some text after the list that few read but all should. It is the key to solve 
many a question related to the way of deciphering  the meaning of the quirks and
shortcomings.

\end{document}
```

Adjust the `leftmargin` to suit, of course.

Comment: This definitively looks like a good solution. If by *how long your paragraph text would be*, you mean the description text for each item it is approximately ten lines (in the text document) at most (using a width of 78 characters.)

Comment: @Zimzalabim: Yes, that's what I meant. If you use a table (even one that breaks across the page boundaries, the breaking only occurs between rows. However, in a list it can occur at the regular end-of-line locations.

Comment: The more I look at it the more I see this is a perfect solution. The documentation for the package have many niceties. I started fiddling with *"figure"* etc. to align the table and so on – but understood I was on my way down the rabbit hole and decided to ask here :) Good save.

Comment: @Zimzalabim: Ultimately you should define your own clone environment (see section  **7 Cloning the basic lists**, p 10 of the [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf)) so you can modify settings globally in a very uniform and consistent way.